# How to change the countdown timer into minutes : seconds?

Tags: javascript

I am designing the game like that, but the countdown timer is still in seconds. So I want to change it into minutes : seconds. How can I change it into minutes : seconds? Please give me an explanation.

```
//thanks to GameAlchemist
function createCountDown(timeRemaining) {
    var startTime = Date.now();
    return function() {
    return timeRemaining - ( Date.now() - startTime );
    }
}
var currentCountDown = createCountDown(30000);
// Draw everything
var render = function () {
var countDownValue = currentCountDown();
returnKillsNeeded(stageNum);
    ctx.drawImage(startGameImg, 0,0);
    ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center'
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    ctx.fillText("press Enter to play", 250, 450);
    ctx.fill();
    if(gameStart){
if (bgReady) {
ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
}
ctx.fillStyle="#522900";
ctx.fillRect(0,480,500,120);
ctx.drawImage(scoreImg, 22,522);
ctx.drawImage(livesImg, 360,522);
ctx.drawImage(progressImg, 200,492);
createProgressBar();
createProgressPercent();
ctx.fillText("progress", 170,492);
setEnemyHealthText();
drawPlayer();
if(countDownValue <=0){
    countDownValue = 0;
}else{
    ctx.fillText(countDownValue, 200,190);
}
```

Comment: If using a plug-in is OK for you, then don't reinvent the wheel. For instance: [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

Comment: The code you provided has unbalanced braces. Please provide code that has correct syntax, and it would be nice if you would indent your code in a logical way.

Comment: Could you provide some feed-back to the answers given, and possible accept an answer that meets your needs?

Comment: Why only seconds that countdown while minutes don't countdown too?

Comment: What do you mean? The variable that has the minutes depends on the number of seconds, so it will also count down, but only once per minute of course. Do you have an issue with any of the provided solutions? If so, which one?

Comment: for PoprostuRonin's answer, I already put var minutes and seconds below var countDownValue and also I have already changed if(countDownValue <=0){
    countDownValue = 0;
}else{
    ctx.fillText(countDownValue, 200,190);
}
into 
if(seconds > 9)
    ctx.fillText(minutes + ":" + seconds, 200,190);
else
    ctx.fillText(minutes + ":0" + seconds, 200,190);
but the minutes don't countdown too

Comment: Did you still keep his `var minutes  = Math.floor(countDownValue/60);`, because that is the line you need to make the minutes decrement. NB: don't post long chunks of code in comments, it is unreadable. At least put them in back-ticks to get some formatting.

Comment: Feel free to comment on my answer, and I will guide you through.

Comment: I have changed "var minutes = Math.floor(countDownValue/1000/60);" but still didn't work. btw thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add a new section " **Edit** ", and add the code you are currently trying with? That way I could check what is going wrong. Don't delete your original question though. Just add to it.

Comment: Do you still need an answer?

Comment: Do you still need an answer? Could you give some feed-back or else accept the answer that meets your needs?

Answer (score 1):

1 minute is 60 seconds, right?

Divide `countDownValue` by 60 to get minutes and round it downwards fe. using `Math.floor()` to make it clean. Modulo `countDownValue` by 60 to get seconds.

```
var minutes = Math.floor(countDownValue/60);
var seconds = countDownValue%60;
```

Then to print time like MM:SS

```
if(seconds > 9)
    ctx.fillText(minutes + ":" + seconds, 200,190);
else
    ctx.fillText(minutes + ":0" + seconds, 200,190);
```

This if statement is to always print time as 7:06, not 7:6

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
ctx.fillText(countDownValue, 200,190);
```

By:

```
// Convert miliseconds to seconds.
var seconds = Math.floor(countDownValue/1000);
// A minute is 60 seconds. See how many times 60 fits in the number of seconds:
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
// Calculate how many seconds are left when removing those minutes:
seconds -= minutes * 60;
// Format the seconds to always have 2 digits
seconds = seconds.toFixed(2);
// Output the result:
ctx.fillText(minutes + ':' + seconds, 200, 190);
```

Some comments:

If using a plug-in is OK for you, then don't reinvent the wheel. For instance: [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

The code you provided has unbalanced braces. That should of course be fixed before your code can run.

Answer (score 0):

convert you millis into minutes and seconds

```
if(countDownValue <=0){
    countDownValue = 0;
}else{
    ctx.fillText(
       (countDownValue/1000/60) << 0 + 
       ':' + 
       (countDownValue/1000) % 60, 200, 190
    );
}
```